# How can I print a a number upto 6 decimal digits in c++?

Tags: c++, double, decimal, precision

I am trying a problem. I need to print the ans in 6 decimal digits. For example if the ans is 64, I want to print 64.000000
I tried the following way. 
what I did wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long t;
    cin>>t;
    float n;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;
        float s=(n-2)*180.000000;
        float w=(s/n)*1.000000;
        cout<<w*1.000000<<setprecision(6)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to use `std::fixed`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: The shown code demonstrates that you are familiar with I/O formatting manipulators, like `std::setprecision`. This is not the only I/O manipulator that's available to you. Are you familiar with all the others? If not, you will find more information in your C++ book.

Comment: Unrelated, but please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `std::fixed`:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

void MyPrint(int i)
{
    double d = static_cast<double>(i);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << d << std::endl;

}

int main() {

    MyPrint(64);
    MyPrint(100);

    return 0;
}
```

[Running the above code online](https://godbolt.org/z/_ZENmG) results in the following output:

```
64.000000
100.000000
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your response. but here's is the thing, I want to print 6 digits after the decimal point for every value. If I input 100 in your code, if prints upto 5 digits after decimal, 4 digits if I input 1000. https://pastebin.com/EWZufxUY here is the code. I want to print 64.000000 for 64, 100.000000 for 100 and 1000.000000 for 1000

Comment: @Tahmid: I updated my answer on the base of your comment.